# Incomplete share list on windows explorer

Tags: automation, windows-explorer

I try to use below code to find all list view items included, it works well if there are no items out of view in Detail View Mode, but if there are lots of list view items, some of them are invisible, namely there is veritical scroll bar showing up in the right, it only can find the visible items, but it works well in other View Mode, such as List.

is there anything wrong here?

AutomationElementCollection items = list.FindAll(TreeScope.Children,
                     new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));
             Logger.WriteWarning("the items totally:"+items.Count); //for exmaple 39/55, not full list items.

here is the screen shot for your reference  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/d6e58ae1-0eb9-43cf-af51-04102a4dd627.

Comment: I have found a workaround to resolve this issue, but still can't find out its root cause why it can't list all, if possible I would like to investigate it to give its final answer.